# MySQL select record customize

Tags: mysql, database

I have mysql record as below

```
| id  | domain_id | name              | type | content      | ttl   | prio | change_date |

| 100 |        12 | www.testdomain.org | A    | 1.1.1.1     | 86400 |    0 |  1231243234 |
```

And I want to select from that table in the field of name only www without .testdomain.org

How can I select and get that result? Please help

regards,

Comment: 1. It looks like it will always be www, wouldn't it? 2. Leave such things to wherever you call the database from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Mysql Split a column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** Based on comments

```
SELECT id, 
       domain_id, 
       LEFT(name, LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '.', -2)) - 1) name,
       type,
       content,
       ttl,
       prio,
       change_date
  FROM table1
```

Sample output:

```
|  ID | DOMAIN_ID |     NAME | TYPE | CONTENT |   TTL | PRIO | CHANGE_DATE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 100 |        12 |      www |    A | 1.1.1.1 | 86400 |    0 |  1231243234 |
| 101 |        12 |    www.a |    A | 1.1.1.1 | 86400 |    0 |  1231243234 |
| 102 |        12 | test.abc |    A | 1.1.1.1 | 86400 |    0 |  1231243234 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26900/5)** demo

Comment: Suppose I have other record something like www.a.testdomain.org or test.abc.domain.net... And I want get only data before .testdomain.org and .domain.net