# Use comma separated list from one table as clause in query for another table

Tags: mysql

I have an `events` table with a field called `breaks`. This is populated with data in a comma separated format, i.e. `1,2,3` or `1` or `1,4,5` - the same format that MySQL's `IN` command uses.

I'd then like to run a query - on the `slots` table - to return all rows apart from those specified in `events.breaks`.

The query, theoretically, should be something like this:

```
SELECT
    `slots`.`id` AS id,
    RIGHT(`slots`.`time`, 8) AS `time`
FROM
    `slots`, `event`
WHERE
    `slots`.`id` NOT IN (`event`.`breaks`)
```

But that doesn't appear to work - if `event.breaks` is `4,5,7`, the only row from the `slots` table that doesn't return is `4`!

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/913fe/1/0

Comment: You should be looking at FIND_IN_SET as a potential solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT slots.id AS id, RIGHT(slots.time, 8) time
FROM slots, event
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(slots.id, event.breaks) = 0
```

This is how the `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)` function works:

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. [...] Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.

Also note that `IN (val1, val2, val3)` is NOT the same as `IN (val4)` where `val4` is a commma-separated string. The IN clause will compare by equality.

Comment: Perfect - but I originally got a `FIND_IN_SET function does not exist` error because of the space between `FIND_IN_SET` and `(`! :) Just in case anyone else is looking for the answer. Thanks Mosty.

Comment: Welcome. Weirdest thing the space issue :)

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a single field to the NOT IN () clause, not a subexpression. Think of it like this

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

is roughly the same as

```
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3;
```

as a subexpression. What you're doing instead is

```
('4,5,7')
```

which is roughly equivalent to

```
SELECT '4,5,7';
```

which in turn MySQL probably converted to a number for the comparison and the result is

```
NOT IN (4)
```

What you're actually trying to do isn't really supposed to be done like that. It'd be better if you added an AxB relation table so you can select several rows with the IDs you don't want.

Comment: Aye, using FIND_IN_SET works, but it'll be cleaner to have a separate table for that with distinct rows for each of the entries you don't want - it'll probably be faster too if your data ends up growing ;).

Answer (score 0):

you may need a subselect to return the split string

```
... NOT IN (SELECT your_split_fnc(`event`.`breaks`) FROM `events`)
```

See answers here for a way to split strings in MySQL [Can Mysql Split a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)

instr() MySQL function could be of help also

```
... INSTR(event.breaks,id) = 0
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr