# mysql count distinct occurrences in an array field

Tags: mysql, arrays, group-by, distinct

I have a text column which contains hashtags used by users. each row contains a different number of hashtags, separed by a space, like this:

```
USERS |  HASHTAG COLUMN:
------------------------
user1 | hashtag1 hashtag2
user2 | hashtag2
user1 | hashtag1 hashtag2 hashtag3 hashtag4
```

I want to get the most used hashtags, in this case my desired output should be:

```
OCCURRENCES | TAG
----------------------
3           | hashtag2
2           | hashtag1
1           | hashtag3
1           | hashtag4
```

I have NO IDEA how to get it, any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You're in for a world of pain: To do what you want with the current design, you'll have to write a parser for that field. You'll need a slight database redesign to get past this and other future problems, because your table is not in first normal form. Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't redesign your database to be in `1NF`, then you can do this in `bash`:

```
echo "select hashtag from table" | \
mysql --user=foo --password=bar --host=hostname --database=dbname --skip-column-names | \
sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | \
sort | \
uniq -c | \
sort -rn
```

The `sed` command puts each hashtag on its own line.  The first `sort` command puts all the duplicate hashtags next to each other so that ... the `uniq` command can count all the occurrences of each one.  The second `sort` command orders the output in reverse numerical order by the counts.

Comment: This is deliciously horrible.