# Mysql Get Unique Values from multi value field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a MySQL table with following structure

```
id       categories
1        ["Pizza","Subs","Sandwiches","Seafood","Italian"]
2        ["Pizza","Salad","Sandwiches","Subs"]
3        ["Fast Food","Burgers","Salad","American","Cafe"]
4        ["Coffee","Cafe"]
```

I need to get list of all unique category names via SQL query

Comment: Do you actually have square brackets in this field?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a maximum of 10 categories.  You can get the list using `substring_index()`.

```
select distinct category
from (select substring_index(substring_index(categories, ',', n.n), ',', -1) as category
      from (select replace(replace(replace(categories, '"', ''), '[', ''), ']', '') as categories
            from t
          ) t cross join
          (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
           select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10
          ) n
      ) c
where category is not null;
```

If you have a longer list, just add more values to the subquery for `n`.  The complex `replace()` assumes that you don't actually want the double quotes and square brackets and that they are not really needed to distinguish among the categories.

As noted in the comments, this is a very bad data structure.  You should have a table for `item_categories` with one row for an item and a single category.

Comment: i think you're missing an extra substring_index call i edited for you. proof here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8d3d/3/0. Nice answer btw!

Comment: Thanks a ton dude, let me find out result.

Comment: @AyazAlavi, you might want to add `AND category != ''` at the end if you have rows that might not have any category like `[]`