# sql query that get the to tags

Tags: mysql, sql

i need help with a query that im trying to creat but im not that good with sql,

i have a table of imgs with a column of tags, in spliting the tags of each images with a ';',

(also tell me if i did good by spliting it this way because i tought about buting the tags in an other table and tag the images by id:))

now im trying to get the top 10 of all tags,

(im getting al this to a php code if it help)

im known as a bad exampler but ill try enyway

Table:  images

### tags

red;baloon;tree

blue;baloon;bycicle

blue;baloon;tree

1st ->baloon

2nd ->blue

3rd -> tree

...

Comment: 1. See normalization. 2. See 1.

Comment: this can get you started (though changing design would be a better option): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Comment: Or this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: can somebody help me with changing of the table structure? i just learn the basic in sql and tables im more a php guy :) i need something that will fit multiple tags for multiple images and the opposite