# Select where in (field which is an imploded array)

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have a field in my database table which is an imploded array of whole numbers that uses commas as glue. These numbers represent ID's for rows within another table.

For example, this field can contain any of the following values:

2
2,5,12
5,6
14
4,12,55
etc.

How would I do a search for all rows which contain, say, "5" in said field?

Lets say I want to find the rows which contain "5", so it would find rows with any of the following for said field:

5
5,12
3,5,8
1,4,5
etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Mysql Split a column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)

Comment: yes it is the same requirement, but August 2009 is a long time ago for MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_in_set()`

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
        -> 2
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

---

However, I don't recommend storing non-normalised data if you are searching for it frequently in particular. Normalised tables of such data can take advantage of indexes.

Comment: I just found it but thank you :) Will mark as solved.

Comment: no problem, the tick may may help other find it too :)