# SQL Splitting in MySQL without own functions

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I have a little problem with some strange strings in one's database table.
I need to split such examples of strings to arrays of INT or separetely to INT looping or sth.

This must be done in 'usual' MySQL (no functions, declares etc - only SELECT statements + built-in-functions like `REPLACE()`, `SUBSTRING()`)

`524;779;` `559;;` `;559;` `411;760;;` + others;

Is such intention possible to perform?

Comment: what is your tables structure is? and what is your expected result?\

Comment: I need to retrieve each INT by sptlitting from field 'some_field' VARCHAR(50) which contains these examples - concated INTS with `;` after each

Comment: Plz specify your desired result.

Comment: This is the result of a bad database design. If you need to store a list of numbers associated to a particular row, then put them in a table with a reference (FK) to the row and the number. If you have 5 numbers, you will have 5 rows. I don't think that you can do anything hare - you're stuffed. If you can retrieve the data into a web page using whatever language you use (php, C#, etc) then you can do the conversion in the code and display however you want. But with SQL alone - nope. Change the database design to something proper.

Comment: Database was created in wrong way by another programmer, now my order is to recreate database in better way using relations and ids, not strange concats of strings.. I need int results from this joined strings. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a run-once operation to convert your data into a sane format, you could take the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008567/17343) and extend it to the maximum number of ids in one string.

Example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63fe3/12).

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, val
FROM (
  SELECT id, substring_index(substring_index(`val`,';',-1),';',1) AS val FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, substring_index(substring_index(`val`,';',-2),';',1) FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, substring_index(substring_index(`val`,';',-3),';',1) FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, substring_index(substring_index(`val`,';',-4),';',1) FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, substring_index(substring_index(`val`,';',-5),';',1) FROM tab
) x
WHERE val <> ''
ORDER BY id
```