# Split a string with no delimiters into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to split a string in a column into one character each into it's own column in SQL Server 2012.

Example: if I have a column with `'ABCDE'`, I need to split it into `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, `'D'`, `'E'`, with each of these into their own columns.

The length of the column to be split may vary, so I need this to be as dynamic as possible.

My question is different from the other post ([Can Mysql Split a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)) since mine doesn't have any delimiters.
Thanks

Comment: select substring(col,1,1) as c1, substring(col,2,1) as c2, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id int, n VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'ABCDEF'),
(2, 'EFGHIJKLMNOPQ')


;WITH cte AS
(SELECT id, n, SUBSTRING(n, 1, 1) c, 1 AS ind FROM @t
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT id, n, SUBSTRING(n, ind + 1, 1), ind + 1 FROM cte WHERE LEN(n) > ind
)

SELECT *
FROM cte 
PIVOT (MAX(c) FOR ind IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[12],[13],[14],[15])) p
```

Output:

```
id  n               1   2   3   4   5   6   7    8    9    10   12   13   14    15
1   ABCDEF          A   B   C   D   E   F   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL  NULL
2   EFGHIJKLMNOPQ   E   F   G   H   I   J   K    L    M    N    P    Q    NULL  NULL
```

Here is dynamic version:

```
DECLARE @l INT, @c VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @l = MAX(LEN(n)) FROM PivotTable

WHILE @l > 0
BEGIN
 SET @c = ',[' + CAST(@l AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ']' + @c
 SET @l = @l - 1
END

SET @c = STUFF(@c, 1, 1,'')

DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT id, n, SUBSTRING(n, 1, 1) c, 1 AS ind FROM PivotTable
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT id, n, SUBSTRING(n, ind + 1, 1), ind + 1 FROM cte WHERE LEN(n) > ind
)

SELECT *
FROM cte 
PIVOT (MAX(c) FOR ind IN(' + @c + ')) p'

EXEC (@s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting the question as putting the characters into one column ("split a string in a column into one character each into it's own column").  However, I realize that this might be ambiguous.

One method is with a recursive CTE:

```
with chars as (
      select left(val, 1) as c, substring(val, 2, len(val)) as rest
      from (select 'ABCDE' as val union all select '123') t
      union all
      select left(rest, 1), substring(rest, 2, len(rest))
      from chars
      where rest <> ''
     )
select c
from chars;
```

Just plug in your table and column in the subquery.  Note that you might want to include other columns as well.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/326) is a SQL Fiddle.

If you want multiple columns *and* the number is not fixed, then you will need 
dynamic SQL.

Comment: That's a good split for something like this, but it leaves rows instead of columns. I think it needs to be paired with a dynamic pivot to give the desired result. If, of course, that is a real, useful desired result. [Which you just addressed a bit in an edit.]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new column for every character you simply need:

```
SELECT  [1] = SUBSTRING(Col, 1, 1),
        [2] = SUBSTRING(Col, 2, 1),
        [3] = SUBSTRING(Col, 3, 1),
        [4] = SUBSTRING(Col, 4, 1),
        [5] = SUBSTRING(Col, 5, 1),
        [6] = SUBSTRING(Col, 6, 1),
        [7] = SUBSTRING(Col, 7, 1),
        [8] = SUBSTRING(Col, 8, 1),
        [9] = SUBSTRING(Col, 9, 1)
FROM    (VALUES ('ABCDE'), ('FGHIJKLMN')) t (Col);
```

Which is fine, if you have a know number of columns. If you have an unknown number of columns, then you just need to generate the same SQL with *n* columns. To do this you will need a numbers table, and since many people do not have one, I will do a quick demo on how to dynamically generate one.

The below will generate a sequential list of numbers, 1 - 100,000,000.

```
WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)
SELECT  Number
FROM    Numbers;
```

It simply uses a table valued constructor to generate 10 rows (`N1`), then cross joins these 10 rows to get 100 rows (`N2`), then cross joins these 100 rows to get 10,000 rows (`N3`) and so on and so on. It finally uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the sequential numbers.

This probably needs to be cut down for this use, I hope you are not splitting a string that is 100,000,000 characters long, but the principle applies. You can just use `TOP` and the maximum length of your string to limit it. For each number you can just build up the necessary repetetive SQL required, which is:

```
,[n] = SUBSTRING(Col, n, 1)
```

So you have something like:

```
SELECT  Number,
        [SQL] = ',[' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(10)) + '] = SUBSTRING(Col, ' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', 1)'
FROM    Numbers;
```

Which gives something like:

```
Number      SQL
-----------------------------------
1       ,[1] = SUBSTRING(Col, 1, 1)
2       ,[2] = SUBSTRING(Col, 2, 1)
3       ,[3] = SUBSTRING(Col, 3, 1)
4       ,[4] = SUBSTRING(Col, 4, 1)
```

The final step is to build up your final statement by concatenating all the text in the column `SQL`; the best way to do this is using SQL Server's XML Extensions.

So your final query might end up like:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;
CREATE TABLE #T (Col VARCHAR(100));
INSERT #T (Col) VALUES ('ABCDE'), ('FGHIJKLMN');

WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)

SELECT  @SQL = 'SELECT Col' + 
                (   SELECT  TOP (SELECT MAX(LEN(Col)) FROM #T) 
                            ',[' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(10)) + '] = SUBSTRING(Col, ' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', 1)'
                    FROM    Numbers
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') + '
                FROM #T;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Which gives:

```
Col         1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
-------------------------------------------------
ABCDE       A   B   C   D   E               
FGHIJKLMN   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
```

Finally, if you actually wanted to split it into rows, I would still use the same approach, with your adhoc numbers table, just join it to your original table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;
CREATE TABLE #T (Col VARCHAR(100));
INSERT #T (Col) VALUES ('ABCDE'), ('FGHIJKLMN');

WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(LEN(Col)) FROM #T) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)

SELECT  t.Col,
        Position = n.Number,
        Character = SUBSTRING(t.Col, n.Number, 1)
FROM    #T AS t
        INNER JOIN Numbers AS n
            ON n.Number <= LEN(t.Col)
ORDER BY t.Col, n.Number;
```

Which gives something like:

```
Col     Position    Character
-------------------------------
ABCDE   1           A
ABCDE   2           B
ABCDE   3           C
ABCDE   4           D
ABCDE   5           E
```

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'ABCDE'
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @i int = 1
while (@i <= len(@str)) begin
    set @sql += case when @i > 1 then ',' else '' end + '''' + substring(@str, @i, 1) + ''''
    set @i += 1 
end

exec('select ' + @sql)
```

(If `'` can appear as a char you would need to substitute `''`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for a dynamic text length.

```
-- Generate demo data
CREATE TABLE #temp(col nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO #temp(col)
VALUES(N'A'),(N'ABC'),(N'DEFGHI'),(N'AB'),(N'KLOMA')

-- Split all in multiple rows
CREATE TABLE #output (col nvarchar(100),part nchar(1), pos int)

;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT col, LEFT(col, 1) as part, 1 as pos
    FROM #temp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col, SUBSTRING(col, pos+1,1) as part, pos+1 as part
    FROM cte
    WHERE LEN(col) > pos
)
INSERT INTO #output(col, part, pos)
    SELECT col, part, pos
    FROM cte

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @columnlist nvarchar(max)

-- Generate Columlist for dynamic pivot
SELECT @columnlist = COALESCE(@columnlist + N',[' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),pos) + ']', N'[' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),pos) + ']')
FROM #output o
WHERE o.col = (SELECT TOP (1) col FROM #output ORDER BY LEN(col) DESC)

-- Pivoting for readability
SET @sql = N'
SELECT pvt.* 
FROM #output o
PIVOT (
    MAX(o.part)
    FOR pos IN('+@columnlist+')
) as pvt'
EXEC (@sql)

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #temp
DROP TABLE #output
```

The keypart is the cte and the pivoting afterwards. If you have any questions, just give me a short feedback.