# Customized search with special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a key-wording module where I want to search data using the comma separated words.And the search is categorized into comma `,` and minus `-`.
Take a look on the example what I exactly want to do is

I have a main table name `tbl_main` in SQL

```
AS_ID   KWD
1   Man,Businessman,Business,Office,confidence,arms crossed
2   Man,Businessman,Business,Office,laptop,corridor,waiting
3   man,business,mobile phone,mobile,phone
4   Welcome,Greeting,beautiful,bride,celebration,wedding,woman,happiness
5   beautiful,bride,wedding,woman,happiness,mobile phone,talking
6   woman,girl,Digital Tablet,working,sitting,online
7   woman,girl,Digital Tablet,working,smiling,happiness,hand on chin
```

> If  search text is =  Man,Businessman then result AS_ID is =1,2
>
> If  search text is =  Man,-Businessman then result AS_ID is =3
>
> If  search text is =  woman,girl,-Working then result AS_ID is =4,5

What is the best why to do this, Help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just to mention. This isn't a good data structure at all. You should split all categories into separate rows which will improve your database in speed and even in the size.

Here an example how I would do this.

Table **AS**:

```
AS_ID (PK)
... your additional field...
```

Table **Categories**:

```
CAT_ID (PK)
CAT_NAME (example: Man)
```

Table **AS_Cats**

```
AS_ID (PK) (FK -> Table AS)
CAT_ID (PK) (FK -> Table Categories)
```

Table **AS_Cats** holds a combined primary key to avoid duplicate categories for one AS.

If you still really want this data structure, you can take a look at the code for splitting strings into rows. This way you can `JOIN` and filter for the `AS_ID` which holds all keys. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782744/split-a-string-with-no-delimiters-into-columns/30783338#30783338).

Comment: I already know about the data structure sir  but it's an old data I can not replace it :( millions of rows added into the table already. @lonic

Comment: Well it can be replaced. Just due to an refactoring process. ;-) But well I've also give you an answer for the fact that you need to stuck on this solution. See the link above.