# how to add commas and single quotes for each character in a string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
declare @data varchar = 'UI'
```

I need to fix this so it'll work with a "IN" statement.

```
'UI' => 'U','I'
```

Having a hard time getting this done. Anyone care to help?

Thanks!

Comment: No chance a `LIKE` would work?

Comment: unfortunately no. has to be an IN statement

Comment: No time to write this tonight, but this should get you going in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782744/split-a-string-with-no-delimiters-into-columns

Comment: If you need it to work with an `IN` statement, then ideally you want to create a custom function that returns a table of characters in a string. e.g. `SELECT a, b, c FROM myTable WHERE someVal IN (SELECT chars FROM dbo.fn_SplitStringSingleChars(@data));` (where dbo.fn_SplitStringSingleChars is the name of your custom function here). Otherwise, you'd be required to do some quite unnecessary dynamic SQL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ad-hoc tally table in concert with Stuff() and XML.

**Example**

```
declare @data varchar(max) = 'UI'

Select S = Stuff((Select ',' +S
    From (
            Select S=''''+substring(@data,N,1)+''''
             From (Select Top (Len(@data)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)) From master..spt_values ) N
        ) B1
    For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

**Returns**

```
'U','I'
```

**Edit If you are open to a UDF**

```
Select S = Stuff((Select ',''' +RetVal + ''''
 From (Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Char](@data)) A 
 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

**The UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Char] (@String varchar(max))
Returns Table
As
Return (
    with   cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N) As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d,cte1 e,cte1 f)

    Select RetSeq=N
          ,RetVal=Substring(@String,N,1) 
     From  cte2
) 
--Max 1 Million Observations
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Char]('this is a string')
```

Comment: thanks, John! I went with your first option. worked out great!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
declare @data varchar = 'UI'
select '''' + @data + ''''
```

to use this in IN Statement:

```
DECLARE @this_Command varchar(1000)
set @this_Command = 'select * from yourtable where column1 in(''' + @data + ''')'
exec(@this_Command);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @JohnCappelletti will serve you well, but unless I'm missing something, I cant help but feel there are easier approaches available.

```
declare @data varchar = 'UI'

Select * from t
where charindex(field,@data)>0
```

This `where` clause will evaluate to `true` if `field` matches any of the characters in the `@data` parameter. There is an edge case which could cause issues: if `field` wasn't always a single character then charindex *could* give you a multi-character match which would have been avoided by @JohnCappelletti's answer. Should that be a relevant concern, you could do this:

```
Select * from t
where charindex(field,@data)>0 AND
len(field)=1
```

If you know `@data` won't contain any 'special' characters (such as `]` or `^`), then you *can* use `like` and would do it as follows:

```
Select * from t
where field like '[' + @data + ']'
```

The `like` will evaluate to `true` if `field` matches any of the characters in the `@data` parameter. If you wanted to do it this way and you do (or could) have special characters in there, you'd need to escape those characters first.

Given that, I'd normally opt for the `charindex` approach. `like` also tends to be less efficient than other functions, though others will know better than I whether it is in this case.

Comment: The issue with the `LIKE` one is you have to be sure that `@data` doesn't contain any surprises. E.g `@data = '^abc'` could cause some surprises (as could anything containing a `]`).

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I was going to include a note to that effect and forgot. I've updated my answer.