# mysql query to search multiple values in comma separated list

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table Orders:

Order VARCHAR(20)

Developer VARCHAR(50)

I need to SELECT field in the following way:

For example I have this data in my Table:

```
Order              Developer

Order 141          Tim (Apple), Alex (Microsoft), Sara (Amazon), Neylo
Order 171          James (Apple), John (Amazon)
Order 181          Nike (Microsoft)
```

Need to make SQL query to get this:

```
Developer                Order

Tim, James (Apple)       Order 141, Order 171
Alex, Nike (Microsoft)   Order 141, Order 181
Sara, John (Amazon)      Order 141, Order 171
Neylo                    Order 141
```

Is this possible to make?
Any idea is welcome

Comment: The best way is to split it up to a new table to be "atomic". you can search for the developer but it may be ambigous.

Comment: Need to keep this table integrated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to use a new table to make it atomic like others mentioned, but it sounds like you can't do that.

If you can add a stored function this solution will work.
http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

If you cannot add a function (e.g. hosted with no admin acces, etc). You could break the data apart using substrings (ugly ugly ugly -- I even hate to mention it it's so bad -- but it could work if you write for the maximum number of supported values).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008567/455627

e.g.

```
 substring_index(`Developer`,',',1) ==> first value
 substring_index(substring_index(`Developer`,',',-2),',',1) ==> second value
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

if this is your database then it is a mess. A golden rule is to have all data only one time in your database. Therefor you should create a table "user" that have all users in his:

user:

- user_id
- name
- email
- ...

Then you could make your order table like this:

order:

- order_id
- user_id
- ...

Now you can get all information like this:

```
SELECT order.order_id, user.name FROM orders
JOIN users ON order.user_id=user.user_id
WHERE order.order_id=141
```

[Understanding JOINS in MySQL](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)