# mysql query to parse string with unknown length

Tags: mysql

Sample pattern is as shown in example,
i want to separate values before and after : (colon)

Sample string pattern: `23:4,13:6^12:1^15:3^45:6,99:2,64:1^.....^`

**Note:** between caps number commas may vary
for e.g

```
 23:4,13:6^  - 1comma
 ^12:1^   - no comma
 ^45:6,99:2,64:1^  - 2 commas
```

Expected output:

```
 ColumnA    ColumnB
 ------------------
    23        4
    13        6
    12        1
    15        3
    45        6
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Share it.

Comment: column a  23,13,12,15,45
column b  4, 6, 1, 3, 6

Comment: Take a look at the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function. It can be used to find the parts of a string before or after a certain number of delimiters.

Comment: i tried with substring index but not working for unknown length string

Comment: Why you want do it with MySQL query? It's match easier do it with other language.. Which one are you using?

Comment: need to use in tool which only requires mysql query

Comment: @prat ok, there's only one solution - stored procedure. It's not posible to do what you want with one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Barmar

I found solution

/* Replaced Special characters with space and took value in Varibale*/

```
  SET @VInput = (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE("23:4,13:6^12:1^15:3^45:6,99:2,64:1^" , ',', ' '), ':', ' '), '^', ' ') FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITION);
```

/* Session varible */

```
  SET @VRow := 0;
```

/* Substring Index to seperate out into coloumn */

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@VInput, ' ', (@VRow := @VRow + 1) * 2 - 1), ' ', -1) as RESP, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@VInput, ' ', (@VRow) * 2), ' ', -1)  as Count FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS` WHERE @VRow * 2 < CHAR_LENGTH(@VInput) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(@VInput, ' ', ''));
```

Thanks Stackoverflow .. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the delimiter characters with spaces.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(colname, ',', ' '), ':', ' '), '^', ' ')
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: trying with this space thing , but after that how to manage that in diffrent columns because unknown length string ?

Comment: That's a very different problem. It's not really possible to make dynamic columns in SQL, you need to use a stored procedure that creates dynamic SQL.

Comment: As someone said in the comments, this would be easier in a real programming language that processes the query results. Then you can split it into an array and process that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column