# Separate the comma values in single row in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have  this table structure

```
 id     flim_name     flim_actor_name
 1      Diwalie       Shah Rukh Khan,Kajol,Varun Dhawan
 2      Mersal        vijay, samantha,kajol
```

I need to convert table in to this structure

```
id     flim_name     Actor_name       Heroin_name  director_name
1       Diwalie      Shah Rukh Khan     Kajol       Varun Dhawan
2       Mersal       vijay              samantha       kajol
```

I need the sql query  to solve this

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

EDIT: Actually, this is a MySQL version which is more suited to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Comment: Are you sure about the tags? mySQL, SQL and Oracle. Which database are you using? Answer may or may not depend on that but still tagging it appropriately will make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: I posted the answer below .Thanks for given the links..

Comment: What is a "flim"?

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: @mathguy I'm more concerned with the heroin!

Comment: Select id, flim_name,
substring_index(substring_index ( `flim_actor_name`,',',1 ), ',',-1)as Hero,
substring_index(substring_index ( `flim_actor_name`,',',2 ), ',', -1)as Heroin,  
substring_index(substring_index(`flim_actor_name`,",",3),',',-1) as director_name   
from flim_management_table

Comment: This the query whatever you need put after as that is what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use implode for this

ex.

```
$arr = array(Shah Rukh Khan,Kajol,Varun Dhawan);
echo implode(" ",$arr);
echo implode(" ",$arr)."<br>";
echo implode("+",$arr)."<br>";
echo implode("-",$arr)."<br>"; 
echo implode("X",$arr);
```

Ouput:

```
Shah Rukh Khan Kajol Varun Dhawan
Shah Rukh Khan+Kajol+Varun Dhawan
Shah Rukh Khan-Kajol-Varun Dhawan
Shah Rukh KhanXKajolXVarun Dhawan
```

Comment: I got solution I posted it below,,,Thanks for all,,

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the question is

```
Select id, flim_name,
substring_index(substring_index ( `flim_actor_name`,',',1 ), ',',-1)as Hero,
substring_index(substring_index ( `flim_actor_name`,',',2 ), ',', -1)as Heroin,  
substring_index(substring_index(`flim_actor_name`,",",3),',',-1) as director_name   
from flim_management_table
```

Table structure:

```
 id      flim_name     Hero             Heroin       director_name
  1       Diwalie      Shah Rukh Khan     Kajol       Varun Dhawan
  2       Mersal       vijay              samantha       kajol
```

Comment: I got a solution..I post it..thanks for all