# Order comma separated strings of a column using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QQPA.jpg)Good day! Paging all database engineers and masters may i have your attention for a while.

I am currently developing our Travel Recommender System and we're having a problem with ORDER BY LIKE SEPARATED COMMAS IN MYSQL.

I have two tables:
-tb_users(this table has a field of "Traveler_Style" where it contains of registered style of what kind of traveler they are. the values of "Traveler_Style" is based on their preferences. Sample value of this is Backpacker, Nightlife)

-attractions(this table has a field of "traveler_style" consist of Backpacker, Nightlife, luxurytraveler )

In my search engine when the user enters an attraction in will ORDER BY LIKE based on the registered "Traveler_Style" on tb_users that will "LIKE" or Match to the record in the table attractions.

I tried to declare a variable to call the value of tb_user Traveler style which is $style_fetch and here's my idea to select the query

```
$query6 = "SELECT * FROM `attractions` WHERE CONCAT(`categories`, `tourist_spot`, `province`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' ORDER BY FIELD(traveler_style, '$style_fetch') DESC limit 8";
```

Expected output should be order by like based on the traveler style of a user

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QQPA.jpg)

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prvent SQL injection

Comment: Hmm is there any sql statement for this kind of query? or trick. i just want to show the result based on the traveler style. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Can you include the table structure and the expected output table in your question? I cannot understand your question.

Comment: Learn about normalization.

Comment: @RaeIan Have you tried something like this? SELECT col1, CONCAT(col2, col3) AS newcol FROM tbl WHERE newcol LIKE '%text%' ORDER BY newcol

Comment: Sir @ClintonLam hmm. I tried sir but not working :( , i just want to order them by like $style_fetch where the value of that variable is coming from the field of tb_users "Traveler_User" the sample value of this column is "Backpacker, Beach Goer" where i cannot use "LIKE in order by because sir the inputted data on the field "Traveler_Style" of table tb_users is separated by commas this data was came from the check box that they selected as who they are as a traveler

Comment: @RaeIan Can you separate Traveler_Style into different column? A better way to do this by separating the table. You should add a table containing Traveler_Style only

Comment: @ClintonLam Very helpful sir. I'll try this Thankyou sir..

Comment: You may change your question title to "Order comma separated strings of a column using MySQL"

Comment: Hello sir, @ClintonLam late reply i already created separated table for traveler style and extracted the data that i needed from table attraction to the new table for styles which is tb_touristspot_styles it results hundreds of rows and the problem is i need to split this given output below and insert again with the same id for identification.

sample table output 

fields ---- **id** | **style**
rows ----    22  |  Beach Goer, Backpacker and so on..

Comment: @RaeIan You should separate Beach Goer and Backpacker into two different row. Please check the answer I gave you below.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it, here are three approaches.

1. Using the MySQL function ***substring_index()***. But you will need to know the number of styles there will be. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column).

   substring_index(`Traveler_Style`,',',1) => first value
   substring_index(substring_index(`Traveler_Style`,',',-2),',',1) => second value
   substring_index(substring_index(`Traveler_Style`,',',-1),',',1) => third value

Something like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Traveler_Style,',',1) AS col1,
       CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Traveler_Style,',',1), 
              substring_index(substring_index(Traveler_Style,',',-2),',',1)) AS col2
FROM table 
WHERE col1 LIKE '%text%' OR
      col2 LIKE '%text%' 
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

2. ***Separate the table column***. You may need to create more columns when needed. Not flexible.
3. ***Create an new table*** so that they can hold multiple traveler styles. You then join the tables and make queries. I prefer this method as it is more flexible and scalability.

   ```
      attractionTable         styleTable
   +===================+   +===============+
   | id | tourist_spot |   | id |    style |
   +===================+   +===============+
   |  1 |  Attraction1 |   |  1 | Backpack |
   |  2 |  Attraction2 |   |  1 |    Beach |
   |  3 |  Attraction3 |   |  2 |    Beach |
   +===================+   |  2 |    Relax |
                           |  3 | Backpack |
                           +===============+
   ```

Notice there is no more comma in traveler style. They are separated in different rows.

In the above example **Attraction1** have 2 related style **Backpack** and **Beach**. **Attraction2** have 2 related style **Beach** and **Relax**. **Attraction3** have 1 style **Backpack**.

Joining the two table and filter by LIKE

```
SELECT tourist_spot, style FROM attractionTable, styleTable 
WHERE attractionTable.id = styleTable.id
  AND style LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY style

    +===============================+
    | id | tourist_spot |     style |
    +===============================+
    |  1 |  Attraction1 |  Backpack |
    |  1 |  Attraction1 |     Beach |
    |  2 |  Attraction2 |     Beach |
    |  2 |  Attraction2 |     Relax |
    |  3 |  Attraction3 |  Backpack |
    +===============================+
```

Now all you need to do is to filter out different style.

Hope this may help.