# Split comma separated values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, substring

I am trying to split comma-separated (,) values into multiple columns from a string

Sample data:

```
     COL1                 COL2            COL3
000002,000003,000042   09,31,51      007,004,007
```

Expected output:

```
Pno       Cno  Sno
000002    09   007
000003    31   004
000042    51   007
```

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT   SUBSTRING_INDEX(COL1, ',', 1) Pno
                 ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(COL2, ',', 1) Cno
                 ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(COL3, ',', 1) Sno
            FROM MyTargetTable
```

Result:

```
Pno        Cno  Sno
000002     09   007
```

I might get more than 3 rows in each columns, I would like to know if there is any way to achieve this without specifying the substring position.

Possible input data could also be like this

```
     COL1                        COL2             COL3
000002,000003,000042,,000002   09,31,51,,32      007,004,007,,012
```

Comment: Simple fix: DON'T have separated values. Normalise your schema!

Comment: @strawberry Appreciate that as a best practice, these values will come into temporary tables from an integration software

Comment: Well, the fact that you may have duplicated values in one column makes this pretty tricky.

Comment: @Strawberry if all 3 columns have duplicate values, we can use distinct from select query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1096679/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea. It assumes you have a table of integers (ints) with values (i) 0-9...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1,',',i+1),',',-1)x
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col2,',',i+1),',',-1)y
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col3,',',i+1),',',-1)z
  FROM my_table
     , ints
 ORDER 
    BY i;
```

Comment: It is returning same values as i have mentioned with my approach in the question, need to get multiple values into each column

Comment: This works fine for me. And you definitely do not need 'to get multiple values into each column'

Comment: I think its due to varchar values in some fields

Comment: This absolutely works perfect with only having int values and referencing int table, i would like to find a solution with varchar values in strings.

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: i have tested this and works fine, accepting your answer. Once again thank you for the solution

Comment: You're welcome, but remember that this is a 'sticking plaster' solution. You have to find a way to fix the way data is coming into your database.