# MySQL select value range within a value range, from a dash-separated column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, range, denormalization

How do I select a value range from a column where two values in it are separated by a dash, using MySQL?

**Here's my example table named "example":**
[image]

The user enters a low value (X) and a high value (Y).
For example X=2.5 and Y=7.2

I want to select all items where the left value is higher than X (in this case 2.5) and the right value is lower than Y (in this case 7.2). Using these X and Y values I should end up with the rows 2 and 5 as a result.

Sort of like this:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE MIN(value) > X AND MAX(value) < Y
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: @Alexey I am using MySQL (edited my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LEFT and RIGHT functions to get X and Y out of your value field.

So I think you are looking for something like this:

`SELECT * FROM example WHERE CAST(LEFT(value,3)AS DECIMAL(2,1)) > 2.5 and CAST(RIGHT(value,3)AS DECIMAL(2,1)) < 7.2`

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot! Is there also a way to do this with 3 or more dash-separated values? I figured there is no such thing as MIDDLE() in this case, is there?

Comment: @3141592653 For sure! I don't work with MySQL though but I found a function called SUBSTRING_INDEX. Here you can split the string based on the delimiter (-). By working with this you don't need to know how long the values are. And there is also a 3rd parameter to the function in which you can specify the number of results.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp

Hope it helps!

Comment: @3141592653 It's a bit weird, but I was able to get this example to work to get the middle of the string seperated by dots.

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX("www.w3schools.com", ".",2),".",-1);

Result: w3Schools.


Here you're basically first making the string look like www.w3schools with the inner Substring function, and then using substring again to get the right side using the 3rd parameter (-1).

Comment: If the value is `10.1-10.2` this suggested query will fail.

Comment: @O.Jones I am basing off of the example data. But yes, then just change the precision as explained in the documentation. E.g. DECIMAL(3,1) for 10.1

Comment: @O.Jones Good to know this!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to access your table in a fashion that only has one value per column. (Multiple values per column, like `3.5-7.5` happen to be a very common relational database design antipattern. They cripple both performance and clarity.)

This SQL subquery does the trick for pairs of values.

```sql
SELECT item_id, name, 
       0.0+SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '-',1) first,
       0.0+SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '-', -1) last
 FROM example;
```

The expression `0.0+something` is a MySQL trick to coerce a value to be numeric.

Then use the subquery to apply your search criteria.

```sql
SELECT item_id, name, first, last
  FROM (       SELECT item_id, name, 
                      0.0+SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '-',1) first,
                      0.0+SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '-', -1) last
                 FROM example
       ) s
 WHERE first > 2.5
   AND last < 7.2;
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=026f7947a4bf009f4d335baf01095e6e).

In a comment you asked about the situation where you have more than two values in a single column separated by delimiters. See this. [Split comma separated values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381854/split-comma-separated-values-in-mysql)

**Pro tip** Don't put more than one number in a column in an RDBMS table. The next person to use the table will be muttering curses all day while trying to use that data.

**Pro tip** Use numeric data types, not VARCHAR(), for numbers.

Comment: Ahh, this basically returns two values as if they were separate columns. Thanks for taking the time to make a fiddle as well.